# Complex Git branch name broke all Git commands

Tags: git, zsh, git-branch, parentheses

I was trying to create a branch from `master` with the following command,

```
git branch SSLOC-201_Implement___str__()_of_ProductSearchQuery
```

when Git suddenly stopped responding. I suspect the unescaped `()` are to blame, somehow. Now, whenever I try to run any Git command, I get the same error:

```
git:176: command not found: _of_ProductSearchQuery
```

with the number after `git` increasing every time I type a command.

Can anyone explain what happened? And how do I get back to normal? I'd like to delete that branch, but how can I do that?

Comment: I would guess this is related to your zsh environment as I was able to run create the branch in my bash shell with no ill side-effects (lubuntu 13.10), but I'm seeing the error when I switch to my totally vanilla zsh

Comment: In the future, quote stuff that looks suspect. `git branch "SSLOC-201_Implement___str__()_of_ProductSearchQuery"` works just fine.

Comment: @Qix Better to avoid problematic characters altogether.

Comment: @Jubobs Definitely, though I've seen certain companies enforce weird branch names like this.

Comment: Be mindful of special characters in your commands: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: @DwightSpencer Your link is specific to Bash, but this question is zsh-specific. The problem doesn't actually occur in Bash.

Comment: @Jubobs Its not about being bash or zsh. The UNIX/OpenGroup standard states there are special characters one uses in a shell command and the '()' characters are just two of the few listed in the link provided.

The issue itself persists across all shells (plan9 rc, tcsh, ash/bash/dash, and zsh/korn) with some of the more commonly installed ones actually given an intelligent error message instead of breaking the script.

But for the sake of documentation: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

Comment: @DwightSpencer We're on the same page, but what I meant is that the particular problem that the OP is experiencing in zsh doesn't occur in bash.

Comment: @Jubobs True, I can confirm that and has been since at lease version 4. As for this being only zsh well that's since zsh is more "power user" thus more BOFH users and less PFY admins so there's no need to teach the user of their wrong doings. While bash, tcsh, and rc it would state syntax error. In older version though it would behave the same as the error above. All in all its still better to document the POSIX standard than x tool solution.

Comment: @DwightSpencer You write: *[...] there's no need to teach the user of their wrong doings*. However, the OP wrote: *Can anyone explain what happened?*. My answer provides an explanation. I also recommend avoiding special shell characters, at the bottom of my answer. Is something missing?

Comment: @Jubobs A patient goes to a doctor and says, "it hurts when I write the letter 'g' ." The doctor responds, "You can be expressive enough with the other letters" I do not like this doctor.

Comment: @Sidnicious Sure, feel free to use parentheses in branch names. However, in my opinion, the need for quoting such names at the command line is a good enough disincentive.

Answer (score 626, accepted):

## Problem

> Can anyone explain what happened? [...] I'd love to be able to delete that branch, but Git won't work for me.

By running

```
git branch SSLOC-201_Implement___str__()_of_ProductSearchQuery
```

in zsh, **you did not create any branch**. Instead, you accidentally defined three *shell functions*, called `git`, `branch`, and `SSLOC-201_Implement___str__`, which ignore their parameters (if any) and whose body is `_of_ProductSearchQuery`. You can check for yourself that this is indeed what happened, by invoking the builtin zsh command called `functions`, which lists all existing shell functions:

```sh
$ functions                                                     
SSLOC-201_Implement___str__ () {
    _of_ProductSearchQuery
}
branch () {
    _of_ProductSearchQuery
}
git () {
    _of_ProductSearchQuery
}
```

Unfortunately, although the other two shell functions are not problematic, **the shell function called "git" now shadows the *bona fide* `git` command!**

```sh
$ which git
git () {
    _of_ProductSearchQuery
}
# but the real "git" is a binary file that lives in /usr/local/bin/git (or some similar path)
```

Therefore, you will subsequently get the error

```
command not found: _of_ProductSearchQuery
```

whenever you attempt to run a Git command, e.g. `git log`, `git status`, etc. (assuming, of course, that no command called `_of_ProductSearchQuery` exists).

### Side note

> [...] I get the same error:
>
> ```
> git:176: command not found: _of_ProductSearchQuery
> ```
>
> (with the number after `git` increasing every time I type a command)

That number simply corresponds to the value of `HISTCMD`, an environment variable that holds

> [t]he current history event number in an interactive shell, in other words the event number for the command that caused `$HISTCMD` to be read.

See the [zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) for more details.

## Solution

> And how do I get back to normal?

Simply delete the problematic shell function (and the other two you created by accident, while you're at it):

```sh
unset -f git
unset -f branch SSLOC-201_Implement___str__
```

Then everything should be fine.

### What if `unset` is shadowed also?!

[Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355540/complex-git-branch-name-broke-all-git-commands/32356243#comment52630960_32356243)! I refer you to [Wumpus W. Wumbley's excellent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355540/complex-git-branch-name-broke-all-git-commands/32356243#comment52780394_32356243) below.

---

### Branch-naming tips

#### Avoid any special shell characters

Yes, as pointed out in the comments, parentheses are valid characters in Git branch names; you just need to quote the name appropriately, e.g.

```sh
$ git branch 'foo()bar'
$ git branch
  foo()bar
* master
$ git checkout 'foo()bar'
Switched to branch 'foo()bar'
```

However, the need for quoting such names *every single time* when used as command-line arguments should convince you to eschew parentheses in reference names. More generally, you should (as much as possible) avoid characters that have a special meaning in shells, to prevent surprises like this one.

#### Use simple branch names

You should keep your branch names short and sweet anyway. Long descriptions like

> SSLOC-201_Implement___str__()_of_ProductSearchQuery

belong in commit messages, not in branch names.

Comment: Couldn't they escape (`\(\)`) the parens, too? Or just use quotes?

Comment: Nothing in that thread states parens are illegal. Git seemed to like it just fine. `Switched to a new branch 'abcd-()-foo'`

Comment: Looks good; definitely not a great idea to use them, but they're not *technically* invalid.

Comment: What happens if someone also shadows `unset` by creating shell function so called? (is this possible?)

Comment: @codroipo Ha! That's a good point. Yes, it is possible, and, in that case, you're probably better off restarting `zsh`.

Comment: You could use `builtin unset`. If `builtin` and `unset` have both been shadowed by functions, then `unfunction`. If that's gone too, `unhash -f`. If all four of those are gone, *then* restart the shell.

Comment: correct solution is actually `_of_ProductSearchQuery()/usr/bin/git`.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why its giving different line number(in an incremental fashion) every time he runs the git commands? `git:176: command not found: _of_ProductSearchQuery`

Comment: @Rao I've touched upon that in my answer; see the part about `HISTCMD`.

Comment: @vidstige That's a rather roundabout way of fixing the problem, but that would work.

Comment: @Jubobs hehe, yeah. Was meant as a phun.