# Promoting local commits to remote from different Branch in GIT

Tags: git, branch, git-merge

In my GIT there are two branches we have created :

1. release/8.25
2. release/8.26

Before `release/8.26` was added I have started making change to `release/8.26` locally in my `release/8.25` and committed them locally.

Now I merged my local `release/8.25` to local `release/8.26` so that I can promote the change from `release/8.26` not from `release/8.25`.

But when I pushed the changes both branches get updated with my code.

I only want to push in `release/8.26`.

Please let me know how I can merge my changes.

Comment: Using backslash (\) in names is seeking for a trouble. :)

Comment: I guess you need smth like `git push <origin> release8.26`

Comment: or you may explicitly specify destination targets with `git push <target_repository> <any_commit_or_branch>:<target_name>`

Comment: A cautionary tale about bad name branches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355540/complex-git-branch-name-broke-all-git-commands

Comment: its forward slash I mistyped this :-)