# Where did this random git branch come from?

Tags: git

When I run the `git branch` command there is a branch listed with `(1)` appended to it, I never created a branch with that name and I can't delete it using the `git branch -d` command. What is it, and how do I delete it? Thanks for your help :)

[image]

**EDIT**

Using accepted answer:
[image]

Comment: Did this git repo live on a Dropbox or something like that? That'd explain where the `(1)` came from.

Comment: Whatever you do, [avoid parentheses in branch names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355540/complex-git-branch-name-broke-all-git-commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its invalid to have that space as part of a branch name, so not clear how it got created, if its actually a real branch.

You can go low level to delete branches by directly manipulating the .git dir. Verify that it's under .git/refs/heads and then remove the file .git/refs/heads/gps-feature-branch* under there. Perhaps this is how the branch name was manipulated like this in the first place (although git wouldn't recognize the space in a branch name, you can add parens here).